# Order of spark optimization rules

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We know that spark has many optimization rules, are there specific ordering requirements for these optimization rules? What are the principles for deciding these orders?

To be more specific, for example, I know ColumnPruning needs to add a project to select fewer columns as close to the data source as possible. pushDownPredicate needs to push predicates as close to the data source as possible.

For these two execution plans, which one is more appropriate?
case1: project near LocalRelation

```
Filter (key#0 < 10)
+- Filter (rand(0) > 0.5)
   +- Project [key#0]
      +- LocalRelation <empty>, [key#0, value#0]
```

case2: filter near LocalRelation

```
Project [key#0]
+- Filter (key#0 < 10)
   +- Filter (rand(0) > 0.5)
      +- LocalRelation <empty>, [key#0, value#0]
```

In the spark unit test, case2 is the expected result

Answer (score 0):

The order and rules used changes in each release (and is different between OSS and Databricks for example).

The actual code is the best place to look for this information (3.5 branch):  [Optimizer.scala defaultBatches](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.5/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer.scala#L72), [batches](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.5/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer.scala#L147) and [nonExcludableRules](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.5/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer.scala#L254)

The batches function shows the path through the various stages.

How a plan ends up looking does depend on implementation, e.g. don't rely on low behaviour in OSS Spark vs a vendor's impl.

Additionally the type of underlying data on file or in memory will affect the plan used.